# What is a good audio library for validating files in Python?

Tags: python, validation, audio, mp3

I'm already checking for content-type, size, and extension ([Django (audio) File Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6194901/django-audio-file-validation)), but I need a library to read the file and confirm that it is in fact what I hope it is (mp3 and mp4 mostly).

I've been here: http://wiki.python.org/moin/Audio/ but no luck. Been at this one for a while, am a bit lost in the woods. Relying on SO big time for this whole end of things...

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I'm already (in Django) using UploadedFile.content_type() :

> "The content-type header uploaded with the file (e.g. text/plain or application/pdf). Like any data supplied by the user, you shouldn't trust that the uploaded file is actually this type. **You'll still need to validate that the file contains the content that the content-type header claims** -- "trust but verify."

So, I'm already reading the header. But how can I validate the actual content of the file?

Comment: maybe just use `file` command?

Comment: file just uses the header as far as I can tell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If just checking the header isn't good enough, I'd recommend using `mutagen` to load the file. It should throw an exception if it's not correct.

FYI, I do not think your approach is very scalable. Is it *really* necessary to read every byte of the file? What is your reason for not trusting the file header?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's necessary to be honest. I'm a newb and am just trying to follow what seems like a strong suggestion from the django docs. This website will be available to anyone and everyone so security **is** potentially an issue (no idea who user is), with that said, if there are better/other ways to go about this, or if it's just unnecessary, I'd definitely value any input above and beyond my explicit question.

Answer (score 2):

You can call a unix sub-shell within python like this:

```
>>> filename = 'Giant Steps.mp3'
>>> import os
>>> type = os.system('file %s' % filename)
Giant Steps.mp3: ISO Media, MPEG v4 system, iTunes AAC-LC
```

** See man pages for more details on the 'file' command if you want to go this route.

[See this post for other options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898669/how-can-i-detect-if-a-file-is-binary-non-text-in-python)

---

Comment: This seems like it wouldn't be a reliable cross-platform solution, but I could be wrong.

Comment: This method just checks the file header as far as I can tell. I'm looking for an actual library that confirms that the file is an audio file.

Comment: As Daenyth said, Mutagen is a great audio library.  I think that the fear in validating audio for django is if someone uploaded a malicious file, they could potentially execute arbitrary code.  For instance, when/if someone plays the malicious file through your website audio player, your audio player should be secure enough not to crash or execute arbitrary code.

Answer (score 0):

Use [sndhdr](http://docs.python.org/library/sndhdr.html)

It does a little more than content-type. Reads the file and gets it's headers..of course this is still not foolproof..using ffmpeg is probably then the only option.